# Python : Multiple Line\any form of graph by defining Matching column values with large datasets

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to Plot this Raw JSON data into graph, doesn't want to have a individual graph for each entity/LDEV value ( will be difficult to compare). For Example : I wanted to create a graph with multiple line plot for LDEV_NUMBER - 00:42:26 , with X-axis value as Record time and Y- Axis value as "READ_IO_COUNT", Similarly, next line graph will represent next LDEV and so on.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
data = b'RECORD_TIME,LDEV_NUMBER,READ_IO_COUNT,WRITE_IO_COUNT,READ_MBYTES,WRITE_MBYTES,READ_RESPONSE_RATE,WRITE_RESPONSE_RATE,TOTAL_RESPONSE_RATE\r\ntime_t,string(16),ulong,ulong,ulong,ulong,float,float,float\r\n2020-03-16 00:00:42,"00:42:26",217,0,1,0,9.200517E+01,0.000000E+00,9.200517E+01\r\n2020-03-16 00:01:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:02:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:03:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:04:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:05:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:06:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:07:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:08:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:09:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:10:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:11:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:12:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:13:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:14:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:15:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:16:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:17:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:18:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:19:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:20:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:21:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:22:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:23:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:24:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:25:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:26:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:27:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:28:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:29:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:30:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:31:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:32:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:33:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:34:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:35:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:36:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:37:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:38:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:39:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:40:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:41:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:42:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:43:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:44:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:45:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:46:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:47:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:48:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:49:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:50:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:51:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:52:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:53:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:54:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:55:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:56:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:57:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:58:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:59:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:00:33,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:01:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:02:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:03:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:04:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:05:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:06:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:07:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:08:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:09:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:10:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:11:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:12:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:13:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:14:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:15:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:16:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:17:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:18:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:19:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:20:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:21:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:22:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:23:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:24:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:25:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:26:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:27:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:28:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:29:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:30:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:31:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:32:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:33:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:34:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:35:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:36:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:37:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:38:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:39:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:40:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:41:02,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:42:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:43:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:44:01,"00:42:26",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:55:02,"00:42:28",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:56:02,"00:42:28",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:57:01,"00:42:28",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:58:01,"00:42:28",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:59:02,"00:42:28",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 02:00:33,"00:42:28",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16  00:17:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:18:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:19:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:20:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:21:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:22:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:23:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:24:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:25:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:26:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:27:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:28:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:29:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:30:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:31:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:32:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:33:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:34:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:35:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:36:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:37:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:38:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:39:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:40:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:41:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:42:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:43:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:44:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:45:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:46:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:47:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:48:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:49:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:50:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:51:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:52:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:53:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:54:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:55:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:56:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:57:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:58:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 00:59:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:00:33,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:01:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:02:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:03:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:04:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:05:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:06:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:07:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:08:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:09:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:10:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:11:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:12:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:13:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:14:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:15:01,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:16:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:17:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:18:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 01:59:02,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n2020-03-16 02:00:33,"00:42:2B",0,0,0,0,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00,0.000000E+00\r\n\r\n'
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data.decode('ascii')))

df1=df.drop(df.index[0])
Lun_name=["00:42:2A","00:42:2B","00:42:27","00:42:26","00:42:28","00:42:29"]

for i in range(len(Lun_name)):
 plt.plot(df.loc[df['LDEV_NUMBER'] =='%s'%Lun_name[i]]['RECORD_TIME'], df.loc[df['LDEV_NUMBER'] == '%s'%Lun_name[i]]['READ_IO_COUNT'])

plt.show()
```

Axes values are disoriented when i try to plot this using above code.

[READ IOPS]

Answer (score 0):

with help of my colleague , i resolved it.Issue here is Y- Axis plotting data value are (for Ex: TOTAL_MBYTES ) with datatype as object , after converting it to integer, the axes looks fine . We did a slight modifications to the code as below

for i in range(len(portname)):
    # plt.plot(df.loc[df['LDEV_NUMBER'] =='%s'%Lun_name[i]]['RECORD_TIME'], df.loc[df['LDEV_NUMBER'] == '%s'%Lun_name[i]]['READ_IO_COUNT'])
    X = list(df1.loc[df1['PORT_NAME'] == '%s' % portname[i]]['DATETIME'])
    Y = list(df1.loc[df1['PORT_NAME'] == '%s' % portname[i]]['TOTAL_MBYTES'])
    ax = plt.axes()
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.HourLocator(interval=4))  # every 4 hours
    ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%H:%M'))  # hours and minutes
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.DayLocator(interval=1))  # every day
    ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n%d-%m-%Y'))

```
for i in range(len(Y)):
    Y[i] = int(Y[i])
plt.plot(X, Y)
plt.ylabel('Processor throughput')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.legend(portname)
```

plt.savefig('port_throughput.png')